# Entity Framework delete sub class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 classes, one is Company and one is Address, i need to delete the address automatically when the company is deleted

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId {get;set;}
    public string Street {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}
}
```

When i delete the Company from database, the address isn't deleted. How can i configure fluent api to delete also his address or using data annotations?

Comment: research cascade on delete fluent API

Comment: i already searched for it and i found a lot of solutions, but every solution is for many to one relationship, i have a one to one relationship and it doesnt work.

Comment: did you try it ?  I didnt know about a 1:M restriction. modelBuilder.Entity<MAIN>()
        .HasOptional(a => a.SECONDARY)
        .WithOptionalDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

Comment: i solved using .Entity<MAIN>() .HasOptional(a => a.SECONDARY) .WithOptionalPrincipal() .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); but i have problems migrating the database with this option

Comment: put answer up for all to see please

Answer (score 0):

i solved using .Entity() .HasOptional(a => a.SECONDARY) .WithOptionalPrincipal() .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); but i have problems migrating the database with this option